# Is there an easy way to detect four near identical images with OpenCV when thresholding is insufficient?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to detect these chevrons from four instances of bluestacks running the same game:

[image: chevrons]

To make it a little easier at a glance to see the differences. These are the same chevrons zoomed. For some reason, bluestacks render them marginally different every time.

[image: chevrons zoomed]

I've tried to use thresholding and different methods with OpenCV but I need to drop it so low I get too many false positives and the different methods don't seem to make a difference.

I'm using `win32gui` for my template:

```
class WindowCapture:

    # properties
    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None
    cropped_x = 0
    cropped_y = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, window_name=None):
        # find the handle for the window we want to capture.
        # if no window name is given, capture the entire screen
        if window_name is None:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        else:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            if not self.hwnd:
                raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

        # get the window size
        window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
        self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
        self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

        # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
        border_pixels = 8
        titlebar_pixels = 40
        self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
        self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
        self.cropped_x = border_pixels
        self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

        # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
        # images into actual screen positions
        self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
        self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

    def get_screenshot(self):

        # get the window image data
        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
        # dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        # free resources
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
        img = img[...,:3]
        img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

        return img

    @staticmethod
    def list_window_names():
        def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    # translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
    # pos = (x, y)
    def get_screen_position(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)
```

And `OpenCV` and `Numpy` for my object detection:

```
class Vision:

    # properties
    needle_img = None
    needle_w = 0
    needle_h = 0
    method = None

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, needle_img_path, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
        self.needle_img = cv.imread(needle_img_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        # Save the dimensions of the needle image
        self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
        self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]

        # There are 6 methods to choose from:
        # TM_CCOEFF, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, TM_CCORR, TM_CCORR_NORMED, TM_SQDIFF, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
        self.method = method

    def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
        # run the OpenCV algorithm
        result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, self.needle_img, self.method)

        # Get the all the positions from the match result that exceed our threshold
        locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
        locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))
        rectangles = []
        for loc in locations:
            rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), self.needle_w, self.needle_h]
            # Add every box to the list twice in order to retain single (non-overlapping) boxes
            rectangles.append(rect)
            rectangles.append(rect)
        # Apply group rectangles
        rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)

        points = []
        if len(rectangles):
            line_color = (0, 255, 0)
            line_type = cv.LINE_4
            marker_color = (255, 0, 255)
            marker_type = cv.MARKER_CROSS

            # Loop over all the rectangles
            for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:

                # Determine the center position
                center_x = x + int(w/2)
                center_y = y + int(h/2)
                # Save the points
                points.append((center_x, center_y))

                if debug_mode == 'rectangles':
                    # Determine the box position
                    top_left = (x, y)
                    bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
                    # Draw the box
                    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color=line_color, 
                                lineType=line_type, thickness=2)
                elif debug_mode == 'points':
                    # Draw the center point
                    cv.drawMarker(haystack_img, (center_x, center_y), 
                                color=marker_color, markerType=marker_type, 
                                markerSize=40, thickness=2)

        return points
```

And then I'm calling the match like this:

```
chevronsicon = Vision('chevrons.jpg')
# checks for chevrons 
chevron = chevronsicon.find(screenshotCropped, 0.86, 'points')
# mouse controls
if chevrons : 
    py.moveTo(chevrons[0])
```

Thresholding and different OpenCV methods have worked every single time I've come across this issue previously. I was considering using a gaussian function to blur the edges and then canny to see if I could get a consistent match but I'm not sure if that's overworking what might be a very simple answer I'm simply not aware of.

Is there an easier way to detect these?

Comment: this might be a reasonable time to mention what you are trying to do here ... if you are trying to click a button could you just use hardcoded positions or something?  if you want to recognize this image in all images you might ever see ... you could try machine learning classification ... basically your goal beyond recognize these things might help determine a different path and you might get some good ideas from someone

Comment: Have you tried cv2.absdiff() on them pair-wise?

Comment: Oh good point Joran, the goal is to click on these yes. I can't hardcode annoyingly as the images will move around. I did consider a classified but I don't have many images I think, there's only maybe 4-8 variations in total to work with and I've never had any success unless I've had hundreds of images. I've not seen  cv2.absdiff() but I'll give it a look!

Comment: cv2.absdiff() computes the absolute difference pixel by pixel. So it shows any differences in the files. But they have to be aligned well.

Comment: Did you try matchTemplate (with different.metrics)? Can you show some sample images?

Comment: When you say different metrics what do you mean Micka? The images at the top are the exact 4, although I've used paint to put them into the once .jpg it's just separated by black lines.